# object detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am looking a simple and an easy algorithm that can determine the location, shape and texture of an object based on pixel intensity of objects in static image.. So that can be used to make the classification of an objects in the given static image..

I want to make my base in object detection topic for static and movable images...
but i am fail to find out basic or simple algorithm for detecting the objects and make the objects classification from the static image..

Any one can help me for a good and right direction...

Expecting a good response thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a pdf](http://www.robocup.hs-weingarten.de/dokumente/report_Boonsieng.pdf) called "The Orange Objects Classification by MATLAB" by **Pramuk Boonsieng** read this, I think this can get you started as they describe very interesting method to classify objects.

Comment: is it necessary to convert the RGB color image to HSI model.. we can't detect or classify the objects based on color intensity and texture of objects in the image..i am doing image processing using visual studio 2010 c++ MFC

Comment: for identifying a specific pixel we can use Xor function for a specific pixel value,,,,if an object have same pixel intensty then we can use Xor function i high light the object in the image..